# How to evalulate xml literal using scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox in runtime?

Tags: xml, scala, reflection, eval

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> def eval(code: String) = {
     |   val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
     |   toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(code))
     | }
eval: (code: String)Any

scala> eval("1 + 2")
res0: Any = 3

scala> eval("<a>b</a>")
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

not found: value $scope
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.throwIfErrors(ToolBoxFactory.scala:316)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.wrapInPackageAndCompile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:198)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:252)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$$anonfun$compile$2.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:429)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$$anonfun$compile$2.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:422)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.liftedTree2$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:355)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:355)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:422)
  at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.eval(ToolBoxFactory.scala:444)
  at .eval(<console>:11)
```

What is the meaning of `not fould: value $scope`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably related to the fact that XML support was extracted in a separate library beginning with scala 2.11, as trying your code snippet in scala 2.10 works like a charm.

It seems it cannot find `$scope: scala.xml.TopScope`.

In scala 2.10.*, it was defined in `Predef`.

Starting with scala 2.11.0, the compiler cannot expect this value to always be available, as you have to include the xml library explicitly.
With this in mind we could wonder if the xml library is accessible to the toolbox. We know it is accessible in the REPL (it is auto-imported), which is easy to check:

```
scala> xml.Text("foo")
res18: scala.xml.Text = foo
scala> <a>b<a>
res19: scala.xml.Elem = <a>b</a>
```

However, is `$scope` itself accessible?

```
scala> $scope
<console>:13: error: not found: value $scope
              $scope
              ^
```

Oops. Why is it not accessible, I honestly don't know, but I think there is actually no more any `$scope` value anywhere even in the xml library and that this value is magically synthetized by the compiler. This magic seems to fail in the toolbox.
For reference, if you try the same in scala 2.10.0 it works fine:

```
scala> $scope
res2: xml.TopScope.type =
```

In any case, this is clearly the root of the problem. If the REPL itself cannot find `$scope` it is not surprising that the toolbox (created from the runtime universe inside the REPL) cannot find it either (and there might be the same problem even outside the REPL).
This can *probably* be classified as a bug (and should at least be reported), but at least there is an ugly but simple workaround:

```
scala> eval("val $scope = scala.xml.TopScope; <a>b</a>")
res22: Any = <a>b</a>
```

Of course you'll actually want to modify `eval` itself to abstract away this hack:

```
def eval(code: String) = {
  val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse("val $scope = scala.xml.TopScope; " + code))
}
```

And now behold:

```
scala> eval("<a>b</a>")
res24: Any = <a>b</a>
```